# Setting language for xml documentation

Tags: visual-studio-2010, documentation

I have localized version of Visual Studio and in new solutions XML-documentation from Base Class Library is displayed in IntelliSense in my language. But when I open solutions downloaded from Internet, this documentation is displayed in English. How can I choose this language?

I looked over project and solution properties and but did not found such setting. Changing language of assembly does not affects this. Possibly IntelliSense language setting is stored in hidden .suo file, but is is in binary format.

Actually I need to change documentation language because I am using GhostDoc and it generates documentation for member overloads in current IntelliSense language while generating all other documentation in English. GhostDoc also does not have such setting.

Answer (score 1):

A little late but the answer is:

There is no such setting.
GhostDoc searches for the documentation of the .NET assemblies which are referenced.

Therefore if an english dll is referrenced, the documentation is in english

It is even worse, existing comments for own written methods seem tobe from file code model of VS, base classes from their documentation.

So you can have the case that you try to "ghostcomment" a method and get english, and another one is displayed in spanish )...